# How to create confirmation mail and send it to user in yii?

Tags: yii

In yii I am creating registration form. After successful registration I want to generate confirmation code and also want to send registration confirmation email to same user. So how can I do this?

Comment: Use phpmailer for that. Check out [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check mail extensions in yii [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/email/)

Answer (score 0):

You can this using a mailer say [swift mailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swiftmailer/) or [phpmailer](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/), add them in your project, include the mailer file in your submit page.

do something like this `require_once(LIB_DIR.'/phpmailer/mail-wrapper.php');` and call function `email()` or `sendEmail()` pass subject, sender address, body, attachment to it and its done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also use Gmail as your SMTP server to avoid spamming and other troubles of mail delivery etc . [Gmail as SMTP](http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server)

Answer (score 0):

The yii user extension has this confirmation email functionality built in: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user/

As Ajet said, using gmail as SMTP makes a lot of sense.